# Hive: Mapreduce File missing

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn

I can enter `Hive-cli` and create new tables. However, when I try to insert data to the table, it says:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://nameservice1/user/yarn/mapreduce/mr-framework/3.0.0-cdh6.0.1-mr-framework.tar.gz
```

but the `HDFS` path `hdfs dfs -ls /user/yarn`  does not exist at all.

The status of `HDFS`, `YARN/MR`, and `Hive` are fine, and I tried to restart all these frameworks. Why `Yarn` did not generate the path on `HDFS` and did not put the tar file to the `HDFS` path?

How to fix this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved: I assume this issue only occurs in `Cloudera Manager` 6.x version.

To solve it, in the cm web page, click `YARN (MR2 Included)` -> `action` -> `Install YARN MapReduce frame jar`.

Then this problem gets solved.